# C# Generic Collection help

Tags: c#, collections

I have a requirement to implement some kind of dictionary object. Something like `MyDict<K,V1, V2)`. For example if I have a Question as Key(k) then Correct answer is V1 . V2 is user selected answer. Is there a collection that would satisfy this requirement in C#. If I have to design my own type, what interfaces should I implement. `ICollection` and `Ilist` ?

Comment: which version of the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4, there are several generic [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) classes that you can use.

So, you can use:

```
Dictionary<T,Tuple<V1,V2>>
```

In earlier versions, you could use [`KeyValuePair<T1,T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) as the second generic type:

```
Dictionary<T,KeyValuePair<V1,V2>>
```

Comment: interesting. There might be multiple right answers in the future too. So I should just create type with out any generics. 
like 

class mytype 
{
   string Question;
   IList<string> CorrectAnswers;
   IList<string> SelectedAnswers;
}

}

Answer (score 1):

Collection classes are defined as part of the `System.Collections` or `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

[Generic Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

something along the lines:

```
        Dictionary<Question,Answer> qDict = new Dictionary<Question, Answer>();

        Answer attempt_v2 = new Answer();
        Question question = new Question();
        if (qDict.ContainsKey(question))
        {
            Answer actual_answerv1 = qDict[question];

            if (actual_answerv1 == attempt_v2)
            {
                // Answers match
            }
        }
```

[Note: I just knocked that up. It may not be the best solution to the problem of matching questions and answers...]

Comment: Thanks for help. Should be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think a new implementation is needed.

OR if your Answer has a property Selected you can create.

```
Dictionary<Question, IList<Answer>>
```

or u can have a type with

```
class Answers {
    Ilist Answers;
    Answer Selected;
}
```